# How to show that $A=B-C$

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

How to show that for a real symmetric matrix $A,~A$ can be written as $A=B-C$ where $B,C$ are positive definite real symmetric matrices?

Please help me ! I'm clueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C=cI$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $c\gt0$ is chosen so that for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, $c+\lambda\gt0$.

Comment: @SritiMallick In particular, you may set $c=1+\sqrt{\operatorname{trace}(A^2)}$.